# Permission denied : Broadcasting Intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Help me Please I am getting this exception , I have no idea what I am doing wrong 
This is my logcat output

```
 Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.notikum.notifypassive.CLUSTER_ID_284 cmp=com.locuslabs.notiphisample/com.notikum.notifypassive.receivers.LocationAlertReceiver (has extras) } from com.locuslabs.notiphisample (pid=-1, uid=10067) requires null due to receiver com.locuslabs.notiphisample/com.notikum.notifypassive.receivers.LocationAlertReceiver
```

Comment: sound like your missing some [permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) in your manifest.

Comment: you probably are missing the location permission

Comment: I have added the permission in my manifest here is my manifest                    <receiver android:name="com.notikum.notifypassive.receivers.LocationAlertReceiver">
    </receiver>

Comment: Is It related with google ? because there server read the manifest file right ?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you are trying to send a broadcast, from another process, to a broadcast receiver that is not exported.

That is just a guess based on the error message -- `requires null` in a `PermissionDenied` error tends to mean the component was not exported.

---

If you take the time to read through StackOverflow and see what questions get good answers, you will see that the questions:

- Post relevant pieces of code, such as the manifest where the receiver is registered and/or where the broadcast is being sent
- Include the full stack trace, rather than picking out one line

In the future, consider including such things in your question, to increase the odds that you will get a good answer, and to reduce the odds that your question will be downvoted or closed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind suggestion I will keep it mind